# Take n rightmost bits of an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, bit-shift

I know how to get the leftmost n bits (say, 8) of an integer:

```py
>>> num = 59840
>>> bin(num)
0b1110100111000000

>>> first_8 = num >> 8
>>> bin(first_8)
0b11101001
```

But I don't understand how to get the n rightmost.

```py
>>> last_8 = num << 8
>>> bin(last_8)

# result
0b111010011100000000000000

# desired
0b11000000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Bitwise and the number with `0b11111111` (a.k.a. `0xFF`<sup>Thanks, [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35812/chris-charley)</sup>).

```
>>> bin(num & 0b11111111)
'0b11000000'
```

**Details:** Your bit-shift attempt doesn't work in Python because integers have arbitrary precision. So when you left-shift 8 bits, you simply get your original number multiplied by 2<sup>8</sup> or 256. In other languages that use fixed-precision integers, the overflowing most-significant bits would be discarded, so you could do `(num << 8) >> 8` to get your desired result. [C++ example](http://cpp.sh/4u5zc)

Also note: The right-shift approach works for the next 8 bits because 59840 is a 16-bit integer. If you try the same thing for something greater than 65535, it wouldn't work. For example:

```
>>> bin(100000 >> 8)
'0b110000110'
```

(Notice this is more than eight bits). A more robust approach would be to bitwise-and to mask out the bits you don't care about, and *then* to right-shift by the correct amount.

```
>>> bin((100000 & 0xFF00) >> 8)
'0b10000110'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant number of bits to get, you can AND those bits with a constant.  But if you have a variable number of bits, there's an easy way to generate the proper mask.

```
def right_most(value, n):
    return value & ((1 << n) - 1)

>>> bin(right_most(0b1110100111000000, 8))
'0b11000000'
```

The `(1 << n)` term generates a one followed by `n` zeroes.  The `- 1` converts those zeros to ones and also eliminates the leading one.